# root login authentication failure, how to use sudo?

Tags: permissions, login, sudo, password, root

My main problem is that I cannot use sudo. My root account is locked using `sudo passwd -dl root`.

I have two users on my machine. root and admin, admin does not have su permission. When I try to use sudo on admin user, it says that admin is not in the sudoers file.

When I try to use su while logged in admin user

```
su: Authentication failure
```

and when I try to use sudo

```
admin is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

can I unlock my root user back?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pkexec gedit /etc/sudoers
```

Then change this:

```
#%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

To

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Not sure if that will do it because my situation was different but I hope so!

Comment: And when asked by `pkexec` for a root password what exactly would you type provided the account is disabled?

Comment: @techraf By default, `pkexec` asks for the password of the user who runs it, and checks if they are allowed to do what they are trying to do with it (like `sudo`). `pkexec` may also display a list of authorized users and ask you to pick which one you wish to authenticate as. Do you have an Ubuntu system where `pkexec` just asks for root's password *even when run by someone in the `sudo` (or on older systems, `admin`) group? If so, is the root password enabled on this system, and has Polkit's configuration even been edited?

Comment: The question explicitly says `admin` is **not** enabled for sudo, neither directly nor through a group membership. `pkexec` will display "Password for root:" prompt in this case. What is the point of your comment?